# SQL server 2005 - 3 table conundrum

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005 running under 2000 compatibility mode.

I have three tables: **`Banks`**, **`Exceptions`** and **`Clients`**; a client is allowed to trade with any bank except those associated with him on the **`exceptions`** table. Basically they look like the below "schema":

```
Banks        Exceptions        Clients
-----        ----------        -------
bkID         bkID              
             clID              clID
```

My question is: how can I find all the clients that have maximum 2 banks with which they're allowed to trade (i.e. not on the **`Exceptions`** table), and one of those two banks being a specific one, always the same for all clients.

An alternate way of rephrasing the question would be: how can I find all the clients that have one specific bank in common (we can choose `JPM` as an example) and at most one other bank, with which they're allowed to trade?

So far I've created a function that counts how many banks are available given a `clID`, however I can't really figure out how to add that condition of all the clients having at least  `JPM` in common...

Thanks All!

**PS:** the function code

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetNbAvailableBanks](@clientID varchar(10))
RETURNS INTEGER
AS
BEGIN 
declare @intReturn integer

set @intReturn = (select 
                        count(*) numBanks
                    from 
                        Banks fxb
                        left outer join Exceptions bx
                            on bx.clID= @clientID and fxb.bkID = bx.bkID
                    where
                        bx.bkID is null
                        and isnull(fxb.bObsolete, 0) = 0)

RETURN @intReturn 
END
```

The query as I'm trying to run it so far:

```
select *
from 
    (select
        clID,
        dbo.fnGetNbAvailableBanks(clID) cnt
    from
        Clients) t
where t.cnt <= 2
```

As you can see as I only return Clients with <= 2 available banks); I need to further filter them to the ones that also contain JPM among those 2 available banks and I'm asking you as I'm looking for an elegant solution.

Comment: Post any code you have, including your function code, maybe it can help and you are not far from the correct solution.

Comment: your design is flawed: the "Exceptions" table should be "AllowedToTradeWith" table.

Comment: Thanks Alex, however as you can imagine, it's not up to me to change the design now. It's a legacy system, it'll take months of regression testing to change anything. Constraints usually foster creativity, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select clID from
(select distinct t1.bkID, t2.clID from Clients t1, Banks t2 
    where t2.bkID not in  
    (select  bkID from  Exceptions t3 where t1.clID = t3.clID ) ) as t1                         
  where clID  not in (select clID from Exceptions where bkID = %yourspecific bankid%)
  group by clID
  having count(*) <= 2
```

You can use hash tables instead select statment in brackets to make this query work faster.

Comment: Flawless, elegant and quite speedy (especially compared to my naïve version). Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

I changed my function to use `EXISTS`, like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FNGETNBAVAILABLEBANKS](@clID VARCHAR(10)) 
returns INTEGER 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @intReturn INTEGER 
      SET @intReturn = (SELECT COUNT(*) numBanks 
                        FROM   (SELECT fxb.bkID 
                                FROM   Banks fxb 
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN Exceptions bx 
                                                    ON bx.clID = @clID 
                                                       AND fxb.bkID = bx.bkID 
                                WHERE  bx.bkID IS NULL 
                                       AND ISNULL(fxb.bObsolete, 0) = 0 
                                       AND EXISTS (SELECT fxb.bkID 
                                                   FROM   Banks fxb 
                                                          LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                          Exceptions bx 
                                                                       ON bx.clID = @clID 
                                                                          AND fxb.bkID = bx.bkID 
                                                   WHERE  bx.bkID IS NULL 
                                                          AND fxb.bkID = 'JPM')) a) 
      RETURN @intReturn 
  END
```

and the query like this:

```
select *
from 
(select
    clID,
    dbo.fnGetNbAvailableBanks(clID) cnt
from
    Clients) t
where t.cnt <= 2 and t.cnt > 0
```

Sorry for the lack of indentation, I don't know why they don't show up... I certainly indented the code...